# How can I version a specific resource in GraphQL

Tags: api, version, graphql

For example, say I am rewriting Facebook and I'd like my API to display previous versions of a Post. Take these for example:

---

**Post 1.0**

"I went to the beach today."

**Post 1.1**

"I went to the beach today **and I got really sunburned.**"

---

I know that GraphQL APIs themselves are versionless but there has to be some way to actually version a specific resource. I'm currently building an app (that I can't disclose details on) and versioning resources/types aren't necessarily a requirement but it is something the company is shooting for. How would I be able to access Post 1.0 and Post 1.1? Is this even possible?

If I can help out more with this question, just let me know. I haven't been able to figure this out so I appreciate any responses!